# Tkinter check if something has been input and display error if it has not

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to make sure that a user types something into a tkinter Entry widget. Basically, if they leave the entry field blank, I want the program to display a popup telling them to enter a valid name. However, this code is not working. I think I am not checking if something has been entered correctly. My guess is that I made a mistake around the `if` statement in the code.

```
def get_name():
    top = Toplevel(root)
    label = Label(top, text="Please input your name.")
    label.pack()
    name = Entry(top)
    if name == ""
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="Please enter a valid name.")
    else:
        pass
    name.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(‘100x100’)
user_entry_var = tk.StringVar()
def validate_user_entry() -> None:
    entry = user_entry_var.get()
    if entry == “”:
        messagebox.showerror(‘Error’, ‘Enter a valid name’)
user_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=user_entry_var).pack()
validate_button = tk.Button(root, text = ‘Check’, command = validate_user_entry).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In your code, name is referring to the Entry widget, not the text. To access the text, you would need to use text variables, and use the get() function to access the entry. I’m not sure what you’re making, but hopefully the code above should help.